# How to check whether a given year is long year in bash?

Tags: bash

How could one check whether a given year is long year in bash?

For ease of use, a function would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This function should return 0 if the passed number is long year, and 1 if it is not.

```
islong() {
    year=$1
    [[ $[$year%4] == 0 && $[$year%100] != 0 || $[$year%400] == 0 ]]
    echo $?
}
```

Using it:

```
$ islong 2000
0
$ islong 2001
1
$ islong 2100
1
```